# What should be the ideal value for Maximum connections in the Websphere Connection pool for more than 125 concurrent users?

Tags: web-services, websphere, connection-pooling

Currently I'm facing the following issue from the websphere server,

> [5/15/18 6:45:20:959 BST] 0000060d FreePool      E   J2CA0045E: Connection not available while invoking method createOrWaitForConnection for resource jdbc/ICWS.

The root cause of J2CA0045E error is,

- Use of Shareable Connections in Long-Running LTC
- Multiple connection requests on same thread without calling close()
- Connection leak in application
- Long-running queries or slow database response time
- Maximum Connections set too low

So I checked all the above mentioned causes and finally found that Maximum connections was set low. The difficulty that I'm facing is to find the ideal number for maximum connections. The webservice that I deployed in websphere has 125 concurrent requests and currently the maximum connection size is 50. But I found that It is not enough. Following are the server specification,

Memory usage at LPAR level is 12 GB out of 14 GB .

Heap :

- initial heap - 512
- max heap size – 2560

Can I set the maximum connection value to 200 or more with the above server specification?

OR

Is there any ideal value for this parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no fixed answer that applies to all usage patterns. It's a matter of tuning. For a starting point, a good guideline is that if you have a web service that requires a single connection each time it is called, then aim to have the maximum number of concurrent web service requests and maximum number of connections match.

Comment: so, its better to have at least same number of requests and connections...right?

Comment: It's a guideline, not a rule, which can be a good starting point for tuning if you have a situation where all of your web requests use one connection and spend a lot of their time performing database operations with it, which is a common pattern. You will really need to experiment with tuning to determine what the optimal values are for your application and workload.